# How to add terminal-notifier when packaging with py2app

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am making an app on mac osx 10.8.2. using python script. I am using terminal-notifier-1.5.1.gem for pop-ups notifications. It is installed on /Library/Ruby. Issue is how to include this while making dist through py2app. So that, pop-up will display in other machines also in which terminal-notifier is not installed.